# why can't call a method inside the btn.setonclicklistener method

Tags: android, android-button, setonerrorlistener

when I try to call a method loadSound in the setonclicklistener ,sound does not appear,but when I call it in onCreateView or onStart method then the sound appears and everything works fine.
what's the problem ?
is there any way to call a method only when pressing buttons ??

and even I called the method setOnLoadCompleteListener inside the setonclicklistener method  and still didn't help.

```js
 public class InsectsFragment extends Fragment {

        private View view;

        private int mBeeSound;


        public InsectsFragment() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_insects, container, false);



            Sound.mSoundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId, int status) {
                    Sound.loaded = true;

                }
            });

            ImageButton beeBtn = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonBee);

            beeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    if (Sound.mStreamID > 0) {
                        Sound.mSoundPool.stop(Sound.mStreamID);
                    }
               mBeeSound = Sound.loadSound(getContext(), "bee.mp3");



                    if (Sound.loaded) {
                        Sound.playSound(mBeeSound);
                        Snackbar.make(view, R.string.Bee, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), R.string.Bee, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }
            });

            return view;
        }
```

Comment: Can you post your Sound.loadSound() method? Have you tried passing InsectsFragment.this.getContext() instead of getContext() ?

Comment: yes I tried, but didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_insects, container, false);

    ImageButton beeBtn = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonBee);

    beeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (Sound.mStreamID > 0) {
                Sound.mSoundPool.stop(Sound.mStreamID);
            }


    Sound.mSoundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId, int status) {
            Sound.loaded = true;

            if (Sound.loaded) {
                Sound.playSound(mBeeSound);
                Snackbar.make(view, R.string.Bee, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), R.string.Bee, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
       mBeeSound = Sound.loadSound(getContext(), "bee.mp3");
      }
        });

    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you pass the right context to soundpool.Inside the setclicklistener may be you are passing the listener's context.